# MVC Model Class not populated on post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, post

I have two MVC models that look like this:

```
public class OtherModel
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Another ID")]
   public int id{ get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "ID")]
   public int id { get; set; }


   public PlayerModel otherModel = new OtherModel ();
}
```

My controller has an [HttpPost] action called USE that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Use(MyModel myModel)
{
   /// myModel.otherModel.id is 0 here!!
}
```

This action takes in a MyModel.  When my form is being posted, the otherModel variable contains a 0 for the id value.  Now, the view that contains the form is handed a MyModel and actually displays the otherModel.id on the page.  The problem is the post action is not
properly marshalling the form data into the otherModel object and I have no clue why.

Another note: When I examine the form data headers for the post, I clearly see otherModel.id with the value that I expect.

Why is this data not appearing correctly within my otherModel object?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you post the form headers that are coming into the controller?

Comment: also it makes me wonder do you set the id and the another id?

Comment: Is otherModel really a public member and not a Property?

Comment: @Jesse - I don't have the EXACT headers right now, in fact, these models above are simplified compare to the real case but this doesn't work either.  The headers definitely contained:  "otherModel.id" and the correct value.  In fact, what i'm doing right now to hack around this is this:  if(!int.TryParse(this.Request.Form["otherModel.id"], out value)).

Comment: @cpoDesign - I do set both IDs.

Comment: @Peter - Yes a public member, not a property.

Comment: I think you should show your Razor code, might be you don't send the model to via Action

Comment: Within the actual form, is the name of the id the same capitalization and within the same "namespace" as what you expecting within your controller action? Without seeing your form it's hard to troubleshoot this.

Comment: otherModel needs to be a property to be assigned from the form post.  There is no setter for the default model binder to use.  See my answer below.

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. - Your comment was the solution!  I made it a property and now it all works well.  I am really new to MVC and this was not obvious to me but it does make sense!

Answer (score 1):

Did you registered binder in Global.asax.cs?

```
public static void RegisterBinders(ModelBinderDictionary binders)
{
   binders.Add(typeof(MyModel), new MyModelBinder());
   // other binders
}
```

This is called in Application_Start like the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   RegisterBinders(ModelBinders.Binders);
}
```

PS: I assumed you are using a custom model binder. In case you are using automatic binding see if you respect the naming conventions.

Comment: He never mentioned that he made a modelbinder for his model, so why would that be a problem?

Comment: You are right. It's my assumption but custom binding eliminates a lot of hassle like this one described above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing `otherModel` with a new object at the line `PlayerModel otherModel = new OtherModel();`, use a property `public PlayerModel otherModel { get; set; }`.  `otherModel` needs a property setter for the model binder to assign the value properly.  This may require you to also change how you populate the `otherModel` property when displaying the view - construct an object and assign it explicitly in either the displaying controller method or some other function that hydrates the model.

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical issue. The fix for me was as Matt mentioned, to make the inner object a property with the needed accessors.

```
public class OuterModel 
{
    public OuterModel ()
    {
        AuxData= new InnerModel();
    }
    public InnerModel AuxData{ get; set; }
}

public class InnerModel
{
     Int Id {get; set;}
}
```